# Function returning pointer into static string

Tags: c, pointers, static, string-literals, storage-duration

I have this program, that prints **Lala**. Although i do not understand why i do not get a compilation error in the main function when i call `foo()`. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that str is `static char*`, but i do not get it.`foo()` returns a pointer to a character. So its call shouln't look like this:
`char* result = foo();`  Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *foo() {
    static char * str = "LalaLalaLalaLala";
    str+=4;
    return str;
}
int main() {
    foo();
    foo();
    printf("%s\n", foo());
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain this to me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you should be getting an error?

Comment: The code looks okay to me (and it would still be okay even if `str` was not declared static, because string-literals are valid for the lifetime of the process)

Comment: If you call `foo` few more times, it will start returning addresses outside the original string invoking undefined behavior. But it will still compile.

Comment: Static variables are not destroyed when the function returns. So you can even return `&str` and it will be valid.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is trivially, "This code compiles because it's valid code." OP will need to explain why they think it's invalid code before we can answer why it's actually valid.

Comment: OP are saying you think `foo();` is what's invalid, and that it should actually be `char* result = foo();`?

Comment: If I'm reading the edit right.... It's legal to ignore a functions return value (even in cases where it's a bad idea; gcc has a way to generate warnings if you don't use the return value of specially annotated functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because a function returns a value doesn't mean you have to use it.  It's perfectly valid (though not necessarily wise depending on the context) to not capture or otherwise use the return value of a function.  The `printf` function returns an `int` value but it's almost never used.

So the line `foo();` is valid code.

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely unimportant that the pointer `str` declared in the function `foo` has static storage duration.

What is important is that the string literal `"LalaLalaLalaLala"` pointed to by the pointer `str` has static storage duration. So a returned pointer from the function is valid until it will point outside the string literal that has type `char[17]` due to the pointer arithmetic within the function

```
str+=4;
```

Pay attention to that in C string literals have static storage duration.
And initially in this declaration

```
static char * str = "LalaLalaLalaLala";
```

the pointer `str` is initialized by the address of the first character of the string literal before the function will get the control and then in each call of the function it is incremented.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *foo() {
    static char * str = "LalaLalaLalaLala";
    char *str1 = something;
```

1. `str` has a **static storage duration** and it is (1) initialized only once, (2) keeps its value between the function calls and (3)identifier `str` is visible only in the function scope
2. `str1` has **automatic storage duration** and it (1) is initialized every time you call the function `foo`, (2) ***does not keep**** its value between the function calls and (3)identifier `str` is visible only in the function scope

Your code is correct and it compiles correctly as you **do not** have to use function return value.

You can force gcc (and probably other compiler too) to warn you if you do not use the return value by using attributes or compile options.

```
[[nodiscard]] char *foo() {
   /* .... */
```

```
<source>:9:5: warning: ignoring return value of 'foo', declared with attribute 'nodiscard' [-Wunused-result]
    9 |     foo();
      |     ^~~~~
```